# Creating a completely dependent concatenation

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functional-dependencies, type-level-computation

A nice true fact about concatenation is that if I know any two variables in the equation:

```
a ++ b = c
```

Then I know the third.

I would like to capture this idea in my own concat so I use a functional dependency.

```
{-# Language DataKinds, GADTs, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies, KindSignatures, PolyKinds, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}
import Data.Kind (Type)

class Concatable
   (m  :: k -> Type)
   (as :: k)
   (bs :: k)
   (cs :: k)
   | as bs -> cs
   , as cs -> bs
   , bs cs -> as
   where
     concat' :: m as -> m bs -> m cs
```

Now I conjure heterogeneous list like so:

```
data HList ( as :: [ Type ] ) where
  HEmpty :: HList '[]
  HCons  :: a -> HList as -> HList (a ': as)
```

But when I try to declare these as `Concatable` I have an issue

```
instance Concatable HList '[] bs bs where
  concat' HEmpty bs = bs
instance
  ( Concatable HList as bs cs
  )
    => Concatable HList (a ': as) bs (a ': cs)
  where
    concat' (HCons head tail) bs = HCons head (concat' tail bs)
```

I don't satisfy my third functional dependency.  Or rather the compiler believes we do not.
This is because the compiler believes that in our second instance it might be the case that `bs ~ (a ': cs)`.  And it could be the case if `Concatable as (a ': cs) cs`.

How can I adjust my instances so that all three of the dependencies are satisfied?

Comment: The key trouble seems to be `bs cs -> as`, because we need non-local information about `bs` and `cs` to decide if `as` should be a cons or a nil.  We need to find out how to represent this information; what context would we add to a type signature to guarantee it when it can't be directly deduced?

Comment: To expand what luqui said: imagine we know `bs` and `cs`, and we want to exploit the fundep, i.e. we want to reconstruct `as`. To do it in a deterministic way, we expect to be able to commit to a single instance and follow that recipe. Concretely, assume `bs = (Int ': bs2)` and `cs = (Int ': cs2)`. Which instance do we choose? It is possible that such `Int` in `cs` comes from `bs` (and `as` is empty). It is also possible that is comes from (nonempty) `as` instead, and that `Int` will appear again in `cs` later on. We need to dig deeper in `cs` to know and GHC won't do that.

Comment: Very roughly put, GHC will accept fundeps that can be proved using a simple form of induction from the instances. Here, one of them requires a kind of double induction to be proved (or so it seems), and the compiler won't go that far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, as comments suggest, GHC is not gonna figure it out on it's own, but we can help it with a bit of type level programming. Let's introduce some `TypeFamilies`. All of these functions are pretty straightforward translations of list manipulation lifted to the type level:

```hs
-- | This will produce the suffix of `cs` without `as`
type family DropPrefix (as :: [Type]) (cs :: [Type]) where
  DropPrefix '[] cs = cs
  DropPrefix (a ': as) (a ': cs) = DropPrefix as cs

-- Similar to the logic in the question itself: list concatenation. 
type family Concat (as :: [Type]) (bs :: [Type]) where
  Concat '[] bs = bs
  Concat (head ': tail) bs = head ': Concat tail bs

-- | Naive list reversal with help of concatenation.
type family Reverse (xs :: [Type]) where
  Reverse '[] = '[]
  Reverse (x ': xs) = Concat (Reverse xs) '[x]

-- | This will produce the prefix of `cs` without `bs`
type family DropSuffix (bs :: [Type]) (cs :: [Type]) where
  DropSuffix bs cs = Reverse (DropPrefix (Reverse bs) (Reverse cs))

-- | Same definition of `HList` as in the question
data HList (as :: [Type]) where
  HEmpty :: HList '[]
  HCons :: a -> HList as -> HList (a ': as)

-- | Definition of concatenation at the value level
concatHList :: (cs ~ Concat as bs) => HList as -> HList bs -> HList cs
concatHList HEmpty bs = bs
concatHList (HCons head tail) bs = HCons head (concatHList tail bs)
```

With this tools at our disposal we can actually get to hour goal, but first let's define a function with the desired properties:

- Ability to deduce `cs` from `as` and `bs`
- Ability to deduce `as` from `bs` and `cs`
- Ability to deduce `bs` from `as` and `cs`

Voila:

```hs
concatH ::
     (cs ~ Concat as bs, bs ~ DropPrefix as cs, as ~ DropSuffix bs cs)
  => HList as
  -> HList bs
  -> HList cs
concatH = concatHList
```

Let's test it:

```
foo :: HList '[Char, Bool]
foo = HCons 'a' (HCons True HEmpty)

bar :: HList '[Int]
bar = HCons (1 :: Int) HEmpty
```

```hs
λ> :t concatH foo bar
concatH foo bar :: HList '[Char, Bool, Int]
λ> :t concatH bar foo
concatH bar foo :: HList '[Int, Char, Bool]
```

And finally the end goal:

```hs
class Concatable (m :: k -> Type) (as :: k) (bs :: k) (cs :: k)
  | as bs -> cs
  , as cs -> bs
  , bs cs -> as
  where
  concat' :: m as -> m bs -> m cs

instance (cs ~ Concat as bs, bs ~ DropPrefix as cs, as ~ DropSuffix bs cs) =>
         Concatable HList as bs cs where
  concat' = concatH
```

```hs
λ> :t concat' HEmpty bar
concat' HEmpty bar :: HList '[Int]
λ> :t concat' foo bar
concat' foo bar :: HList '[Char, Bool, Int]
λ> :t concat' bar foo
concat' bar foo :: HList '[Int, Char, Bool]
```

Comment: Well done!  I even suspected this might be impossible but you solved it transparently and elegantly.